# Math and engineering questions: where do we draw the line?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

I was reading through some old meta discussions recently, and I was interested in some of the points made, but they never quite seemed to be implemented or discussed further. They also seemed to be buried among the various conversations about physics overflow and the various controversies surrounding that. So, I am asking the current community what they think of the following points; I will post my own personal opinion as an answer soon.

1. Too many questions that have math in them are closed.
2. The current stance on engineering questions is too harsh.

Opinions on these two appreciated. Thanks!

---

**Previous Meta Posts:**

- [Asking math questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5473/asking-math-questions)
- [Are questions about mathematics used in physics always off topic?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7140/are-questions-about-mathematics-used-in-physics-always-off-topic)
- [Should pure math questions be on topic?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5713/should-pure-math-questions-be-on-topic)
- [Are engineering questions OK?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65/are-engineering-questions-ok)
- [Are engineering questions appropriate for this site?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4535/are-engineering-questions-appropriate-for-this-site)
- [What is engineering and what is experimental design?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5553/what-is-engineering-and-what-is-experimental-design)

Comment: Can you link to the threads you have read recently so we are all on the same page? And so we can add any missing ones that might help fill in the gaps

Comment: Related: Math: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/5713/2451 , http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/7140/2451 Engineering: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/65/2451, http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4535/2451

Comment: Also related: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/5553/

Comment: @tpg2114, sorry I didn't answer earlier - just got off from school; I posted this during study hall. The ones you and Qmechanic listed are some of the main ones; there is one more I read that I'm looking for but so far have not found; I'll let you know when I find it.

Comment: @tpg2114, found it, and added it and Qmechanic/your links to my post as a reference.

Comment: @heather Thanks -- that helps make sure everybody is brought up to speed with the current status.

Comment: @tpg2114, no problem - sorry I didn't post them right off the bat. =) Aside from that, do you have any opinion on the points?

Comment: @heather I do -- but I don't know that my opinion is very different from what I have already contributed in those linked references. I may participate in the discussion once it gets rolling, but I'm fine with the way things are now and don't feel the need to start it rolling myself.

Comment: Your third example was closed for being unclear, and your first two examples were closed as *homework*, not for being math or engineering questions. I'm not sure what your point is in listing these.

Comment: Further to @ACuriousMind's point, I'm also unsure why you're bringing up closures from 2013 and 2014.